# Conditional scalacOptions with SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-2.10

I am using a project with cross-build for Scala 2.8, 2.9 and (hopefully) 2.10, using SBT. I would like to add the `-feature` option when compiling with 2.10 only.

In other words, when I compile with a version smaller than 2.10.0, I would like to set the compiler options as:

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq( "-deprecation", "-unchecked" )
```

and when compiling with a version greater or equal than 2.10.0:

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq( "-deprecation", "-unchecked", "-feature" )
```

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: take a look at scalaz: https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When cross-building, scalaVersion reflects the version your project is currently built against. So depending on scalaVersion should do the trick:

```
val scalaVersionRegex = "(\\d+)\\.(\\d+).*".r
...
scalacOptions <++= scalaVersion { sv =>
  sv match {
    case scalaVersionRegex(major, minor) if major.toInt > 2 || (major == "2" && minor.toInt >= 10) =>
      Seq( "-deprecation", "-unchecked", "-feature" )
    case _ => Seq( "-deprecation", "-unchecked" )
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I found this was quick and concise way of doing it:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.0"

crossScalaVersions := "2.9.2" :: "2.10.0" :: Nil

scalacOptions <<= scalaVersion map { v: String =>
  val default = "-deprecation" :: "-unchecked" :: Nil
  if (v.startsWith("2.9.")) default else default :+ "-feature"            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [CrossVersion.partialVersion](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Cross-Build.html#Change+settings+depending+on+the+Scala+version) now which can be used for this. I am not sure which SBT it was introduced in, but it seems to work fine even in 0.13.8:

```
    scalacOptions ++= {
      if (CrossVersion.partialVersion(scalaVersion.value).exists(_ >= (2, 10))) {
        Seq("-deprecation", "-unchecked", "-feature")
      } else {
        Seq("-deprecation", "-unchecked")
      }
    }
```

Note: you need to `import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._` to be able to use `>=` operator on tuples.