# Comparing versions in sbt

Tags: scala, version, sbt

Is there a simple way to compare versions in sbt build files without handcrafting. E.g.

```
scalacOptions <++= scalaVersion { sv =>
  if (sv >= "2.10.0") "-feature" :: Nil else Nil
}
```

(The above compiles, but for some reason `"2.9.2" >= "2.10.0"` ... ?!)

Comment: I mean, don't tell me [this is the recommended way to compare versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626197/conditional-scalacoptions-with-sbt#12628568)

Comment: Those are strings, you know... "2.9.2" _is_ greater than "2.10.0"!

Comment: Yes I was surprised that by default an implicit `Ordering` with lexicographic rules seems to be in place. But surely sbt has some comparison function somewhere that breaks down the strings properly?

Comment: Take a look at the way scalaz uses scalaVersion. It looks like they use pattern matching and not string comparisions: https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/project/ScalazBuild.scala

Comment: `case "2.9.1" | "2.9.2" | "2.9.3-RC1" | "2.10.0" => ...` doesn't convince me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional scalacOptions with SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626197/conditional-scalacoptions-with-sbt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since sbt 1.2.0 there's a built-in API: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/sbt-1.2-Release-Notes.html#Semantic+Version+selector+API

For example you can do

```
VersionNumber("2.12.5").matchesSemVer(SemanticSelector(">=2.12"))
```

Answer (score 3):

[semverfi](https://github.com/softprops/semverfi) is a Scala library that you can add to your `project/plugins.sbt` and it will be available for use in build definitions:

```
libraryDependencies += "me.lessis" %% "semverfi" % "0.1.2"
```