# How to set different scalacOptions per Scala version when cross-compiling using Build.scala?

Tags: scala, sbt, cross-compiling

When building with Scala 2.10 and SBT 0.13.2, I want to have `-language:_`, but this isn't recognized by Scala 2.9. There's a question about settings different `scalacOptions` for cross-compilation ([Conditional scalacOptions with SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626197/conditional-scalacoptions-with-sbt)), but it is about `build.sbt`. I'm using `Build.scala` because I'm doing a multi-project build.

I have tried this:

```
  def scalacOptionsVersion(v: String) = {
    Seq(
      "-unchecked",
      "-deprecation",
      "-Xlint",
      "-Xfatal-warnings",
      "-Ywarn-dead-code",
      "-target:jvm-1.7",
      "-encoding", "UTF-8") ++ (
    if (v.startsWith("2.9")) Seq() else Seq("-language:_"))
  }

  override val settings = super.settings ++ Seq(
    ...,
    scalaVersion := "2.10.4",
    scalacOptions <++= scalaVersion(scalacOptionsVersion),
    crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.9.2", "2.10.4", "2.11.4"),
    ...
  )
```

but I get an error:

```
[error] /Users/benwing/devel/lemkit/scala/project/build.scala:29: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : sbt.Def.Initialize[Equals]
[error]  required: sbt.Def.Initialize[sbt.Task[?]]
[error] Note: Equals >: sbt.Task[?], but trait Initialize is invariant in type T.
[error] You may wish to define T as -T instead. (SLS 4.5)
[error]     scalacOptions <++= scalaVersion(scalacOptionsVersion),
[error]                                    ^
[error] one error found
```

Help?

Comment: What version of sbt ?

Comment: My project is designed for 0.13.2. Maybe there's a way of doing multi-project builds using `build.sbt` but I don't know how and it seems the answer shouldn't require switching your whole build script.

Comment: Just included SBT version in question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In SBT 0.13+ this will work:

```scala
def scalacOptionsVersion(scalaVersion: String) = {
  Seq(
    "-unchecked",
    "-deprecation",
    "-Xlint",
    "-Xfatal-warnings",
    "-Ywarn-dead-code",
    "-target:jvm-1.7",
    "-encoding", "UTF-8"
  ) ++ CrossVersion.partialVersion(scalaVersion) match {
         case Some((2, scalaMajor)) if scalaMajor == 9 => Nil
         case _ => Seq("-language:_")
       }
}


val appSettings = Seq(
  scalacOptions := scalacOptionsVersion(scalaVersion.value)

  // other settings...
)
```

Comment: Wow, we're actually using sbt-scoverage! Or at least, we were for this project, but I had to comment it out for 2.9 cross-compilation. Any idea how to work around this problem, or does sbt-scoverage just not support 2.9?

Comment: The sbt plugin supports 0.13+, the scoverage scalac plugin only supports 2.11 (and mostly works on 2.10 but its officially unsupported). In version 1.0+, you activate it via the command line, so not sure how to selectively enable, let me think.

Comment: Thanks! As you might have guessed, I'm using sbt-scoverage 0.x (specifically 0.99.7.1); also sbt-coveralls 0.99.0. These are added using `addSbtPlugin`.